# If/then constraint formulation

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, constraint-programming, logical-constraints

Let's assume we have event $i=1,2,\cdots,k$, denoted as $\text{event}_i$. We know for a fact that $\text{event}_i$ is smaller then $\text{event}_{i+1}$ i.e., $\text{event}_i \leq \text{event}_{i+1}$. Now we have given some events $a,b,c,d \leq k$. How do I formulate the constraint that: if $\text{event}_a \leq \text{event}_b$ then $\text{event}_c \leq \text{event}_d$?

My try was:

\begin{align}\text{event}_a + Mz &> \text{event}_b\\\text{event}_c + M(1-z) &\leq \text{event}_d\end{align} where $z \in\{0,1\}$, $M$ large.

Comment: Given that you have weak inequalities, do you mean that each event is *no larger* than the subsequent event?

Comment: I must have that if event a is before event b then event c must be before event d

Comment: Your formulation seems to be ok. Just try with a solver or in excel to confirm.

Comment: How would you formulate a constraint which has to be like: Either event a is before event b or event a is before event c, or both.

Comment: "Either a is before b or a is before c" is the same as "if b is before a then a is before c".

Comment: Also, just for completeness, your big M attempt is wrong. It forces c to precede d regardless of what a and be are doing, and if $z=0$ it forces $\textrm{event}_d$ to take a very large value.

Comment: Can you give the right constraints, that would help me alot.

Comment: The right constraints are in my answer. This is what I meant by needing the opposite sign in your second big-M constraint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to enforce the logical implication
$$\text{event}_a \leq \text{event}_b \implies \text{event}_c \leq \text{event}_d.$$
Introduce a binary variable $z$ and enforce
\begin{align}
\text{event}_a \leq \text{event}_b \implies z = 1 \tag1\label1\\
z = 1 \implies \text{event}_c \leq \text{event}_d \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Equivalently, by contraposition of \eqref{1},
\begin{align}
z = 0 \implies \text{event}_a > \text{event}_b  \tag3\label3\\
z = 1 \implies \text{event}_c \leq \text{event}_d  \tag4\label4
\end{align}
Now big-M modeling yields
\begin{align}
\text{event}_b - \text{event}_a &< M_1 z \tag5\label5\\
\text{event}_c - \text{event}_d &\le M_2(1-z) \tag6\label6
\end{align}
This is very similar to what you tried, except that your second $M$ needs the opposite sign.
Because MILP disallows strict inequalities, you need to introduce a positive tolerance $\epsilon$ and replace \eqref{5} with
$$\text{event}_b - \text{event}_a +\epsilon \le M_1 z.$$
The effect is that you are enforcing
$$\text{event}_a - \epsilon < \text{event}_b \implies \text{event}_c \leq \text{event}_d.$$